# How to create hard link on directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

I know that it is forbidden to create hard links on directories because of the memory errors it will cause, but I want to bypass this restriction. Can it be done?

I create links by using `ln` and after I try to do something like `ln dir1 dir2` I get `ln: dir1: hard link not allowed for directory`

Comment: What syntax command are you running, and what error are you getting exactly? Please [edit] to include this to assist in helping get an answer.

Comment: Related: [*Why are hard links to directories not allowed in UNIX/Linux?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22394/108618)

Comment: Why do you need such link? Do you really, really want to bypass this restriction specifically? Or is there an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here? Maybe the underlying problem can be solved in another, supported, not hacky way.

Comment: Can a bind mount fix your problem?

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski, I just want to create a labyrinth from theese nested directories as a joke :)

Comment: Soft links might work for that, but the only other way is to construct a (preferably) read only filesystem by hand either programmatically or with a binary editor or filesystem editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't create hard links on directories is not because of memory.  It's because it would create a loop in the filesystem hierarchy and it is prohibited by the filesystem.  This can't be bypassed.

If you want a link to a directory there are several options:

- symbolic links (`ln -s`)
- bind mounts (root only)
- nfs mounts (and other network filesystems) (root only, exported filesystems only)

Having said that, it is actually possible to indirectly make hard links to directories.  Every directory has two hard links to directories in it -- `.` which links to the directory itself and `..` which links to the parent directory.  So if you check the number of hard links a directory has, this is how many subdirectories are in it.  And you can create more hard links by making more subdirectories.  (Note that some filesystems generate these on the fly and don't actually store them.)

Comment: but this loop will cause memory allocation error. It is like putting an item into infinitely wide bag. You don't know where it is exaclty. The same thing is with memory

Comment: Actually, I can confuse filesystem partition and memory allocation logic

Comment: Ya, this has nothing to do with memory.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, if your chosen filesystem has a tool like `debugfs` or `xfs_db`. Use it to create a directory entry that points at your chosen inode number. However, the filesystem checks will probably keep attempting to correct it every time.

If you have a situation where the link needs to cross into/out of a chroot or similar, use a bind mount instead. (Most container or sandbox tools already know how to set up bind mounts.)

Answer (score 0):

I did it once,  it was on extfs on kernel 0.95
Linux Soft Landing System distro.

Afterwards I was unable to unlink the doubly linked directory

Comment: That sounds like a bug that was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated, it is not possible to create hardlinks on directories for some reasons. I think the most important one is the fact that it would be possible to accidentally create file tree structures with infinite depth.

However, with `cp -lR <src-dir> <dest-dir>` you can create hardlinks for every file recursively. This has not exactly the same semantics because each directory is still copied and not hardlinked but every file is, but I guess it is very close to what you might need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is interesting indeed that `cp` has such an option!